# Python df.to_sql Results in Hanging and Suspension

Tags: python, sql, dataframe

I have an intermittent issue where when I try to insert a dataframe to a sql table it just hangs and does not complete. When I check using sp_whoisactive it shows the process is suspended.

This is the Python bit related to the insertion.

```
        engine_insert = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))
        conn_insert = engine_insert.raw_connection()
        print("Inserting " + str(len(insertDf)) + " to db")
        print(" - Insert to DB")
        
        # Python/SQL hangs here
        insertDf.to_sql(name="RecommendedMembers", con=engine_insert, if_exists="append", schema="EDWanalytics.ML", index=False)
        conn_insert.commit()
        
        # This part never gets reached ... SQL hangs at above
        cursor_insert = conn_insert.cursor()
        query = """
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
            exec EDWAnalytics.ML.pUpdateAccountNumbers;
            exec EDWAnalytics.ML.pUpdateRecommendationHash;
            exec EDWAnalytics.ML.pParseRecommendationFactors;
            exec EDWAnalytics.ML.pUpdateLatestRecommendations;            
            """
        cursor_insert.execute(query)
```

Comment: Anything guys? Still couldn't resolve this issue even with more research.